# sending array of edited array of files(images) to php script

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form containing an input of type file that can accept multiple files(images) as shown below:

```
  <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="fileupload[]" multiple   />
```

Once a user selects an image or multiple images they are added dynamically to the website and also the user can remove one or all of them if he wants to.

Is there a way I can update which files are chosen from the input element to send to php script?

If not how can I send  only images the user chooses? I mean I can put what the user chose in another array in JavaScript but how can I send them to php script?

**Edited**

**In more details** for example when the user chooses three image files there is JavaScript code i use that appends them into screen as images and the user is given the option to remove one or all of them by clicking on them. So my problem is if the user for example removed one of the images how can I send only the other two images into the php script?

I am not looking for complete code. I am just looking for a hint on how to accomplish it.

Comment: Have you written any PHP? SO is not a code writing service, it's for fixing *existing* code.

Comment: @Oisin - I think the question is how to send to the php script, not what should be in the php script.

Comment: @has19 - can you please post the code showing how the user chooses images?

Comment: @ devlin carnate  yes exactly i know how to upload multiple images to database but the thing is if a user remove one of the images how i am suppose to send only the edited list to the php script

Comment: @has19 - show us the code which allows the user to remove an image.  we need to see how you're implementing that logic.

Comment: you can't use an upload form to remove something - i think your question is missing some detail\

Comment: @Dagon i have a javascript code that append the selected images into the website as img element and the user can remove one of them by clicking on them so what i want is to send only the images the user didn't remove not all of them to the php script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've understood what you want.

Combine Ajax with [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) to get that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#data").submit(function(){

        // create your filtred list of files from your file input
        var data = {};
        $.each($('#fileupload')[0].files, function(i, file) {

            // Keep only the files that the user has selected
            if ( i % 2 == 0){ // <--- CHANGE THIS
                data['file-'+i] = file;
            }
        });

        // create a FormData (to send files with AJAX)
        var formData = new FormData();
        for (var key in data) {
          formData.append(key, data[key]);
        }

        // send that formData
        php_script_url = "your_script.php"
        $.ajax({
            url: php_script_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Don't forget to include `jQuery` before this script

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok i think this is the right answer .i did exactly as you said but i am trying to access for example one of the files included within the data variable send  from php script using $_POST['file-0'] it is returning null. i already debug the javascript code and the data variable is set as expected .

Comment: if i append a string to formdata instead of files it works but not with files although i check the javascript code and the data array contains the files as expected.

Comment: thx you very much i was accessing the files wrongly with $_POST i should access them with $_FILES